# Custom relational fields Django

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

```
### MODEL ###
TITLE_CHOICES = (
    ('Ж', 'Ж'),
    ('М', 'М'),
)


class Master(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=30, choices=TITLE_CHOICES)
    birth_date = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    work = models.ForeignKey(Salon, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name='masters', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return '{}'.format(self.first_name)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['created']    


### Like ME ###
    class Like(models.Model):
        salon = models.OneToOneField(Salon, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        master = models.OneToOneField(Master, related_name='masters', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        owner = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name='likes', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        created = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)

        class Meta:
            ordering = ['created']

        def __str__(self):
            return 'salon: {}, salon_id: {}, master: {}, master_id: {}'.format(self.salon, self.salon.id, self.master,
                                                                               self.master.id)


        ### SERIALZERS ###

        ### MASTERS ###
class MasterSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    owner = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='owner.username')
    work = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='work.salon_name')

    class Meta:
        model = Master
        fields = ('first_name', 'last_name', 'title', 'birth_date', 'work', 'owner', 'id')



        ### Like ME ###
        class LikeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
            owner = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='owner.username')

            class Meta:
                model = Like
                fields = ('salon', 'master', 'owner', 'id' )

        ### USER MODEL ###
        class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
            password = serializers.CharField(write_only=True)

            class Meta:
                model = User
                fields = ('url', 'id', 'likes', 'username', 'phone', 'password')
```

Вывод

```
GET /api/v1/users/
HTTP 200 OK
Allow: GET, HEAD, OPTIONS
Content-Type: application/json
Vary: Accept

{
    "count": 1,
    "next": null,
    "previous": null,
    "results": [
        {
            "url": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/users/1/",
            "id": 1,
            "likes": [
                {
                    "salon": 1,
                    "master": 1,
                    "owner": "boris",
                    "id": 1
                }
            ],
            "username": "boris",
            "phone": "79636341316"
        }
    ]
}
```

Как сделать так, чтобы в `Likes serialzers`, вместо `id` связной модели `master` выводилось имя мастера (`first_name`) и при этом оставалась возможность создания записи.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class LikeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    owner = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='owner.username')
    master = serializers.SlugRelatedField(queryset=Master.objects.all(), slug_field='first_name')

    class Meta:
        model = Like
        fields = ('salon', 'master', 'owner', 'id' )
```

Comment: Подскажите,  как при такой конфигурации сохранить возможность создания записей по id, а не slug_field?